# How to have a PHP redirect on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, redirect, post-redirect-get

I want to have a URL like this `www.example.com/redirect.php?www.google.com` in my WordPress website:

Every time I change `www.google.com` to another URL it will redirect to that page. I also want to have some urls to show as `example.com/redirect.php?www.google.com` but redirects to `affiliate.google.com`.

If there is any plugin please mention that.

Comment: Why you didn't answered but edited my question ?

Answer (score 0):

create redirect.php and upload it on your wordpress root folder

the and this file

```
<?php
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $query)) {
    $url = "http://" . $query;
    header('Location: '.$url);
}
```

Comment: ok, then what if I want people to see different URL after ? but redirectet to somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$links=array
(
'www.google.com'=>'http://google.com',
'google.co'=>'http://google.co.uk',
'google.af'=>'http://google.com.af'
// etc... last line without comma
);
if (array_key_exists($_GET[id],$links))
{
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:" . $links[$_GET[id]]);
}
else {echo "bad url";}
exit(); ?>
```

here is the code I was able to find, create a file called redirect.php or other type paste the code and then when you write `www.yoursite.com/redirect.php?id=google.co` it will redirect to `google.co.uk`